# Can I detect/measure strength of a FM radio wave using a Electro magnetic field meter?

Tags: everyday-life, radio, radio-frequency

I understand that an alternating current produces an Electro magnetic field . The strength of this magnetic field can be measured by measuring devices. What I wanted to understand is

1. Are the FM waves generated by the radio transmitters a form of Electro magnetic field?
2. Given an EMF meter such as [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superphunlabs.emf), can I detect the strength of such a wave/field that is coming my way?

I have a basic understanding of how a magnetic field is generated by an alternating current and how it varies inversely with the distance from source. But I do not have an in depth understanding of this area. I am trying to understand the correspondence between the radio waves and the Electro magnetic field and then go forward on application from there.